# Oracle index fragmentation

Tags: database, oracle, oracle19c

I would like to know if there is any way other than "analyze index validate structure" to find out index fragmentation in Oracle database? As this causes row lock in a production environment.
"analyze index validate structure online" doesn't populate the index_stats.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your optimizer statistics are relatively current, you can do something like

- get number of LEAF_BLOCKS from USER_INDEXES
- get NUM_ROWS from USER_INDEXES
- get AVG_COL_LEN for each column in the index from USER_TABLES

Summing the column lengths, plus 6 bytes for the rowid, times the number of rows  gives you a total byte figure for the index entries.

Depending on the data within it, and how that data was inserted, an index will typically sit at around 65-90% full. Throw in some block level overheads (lets say 200 bytes per 8k block), and you can use this get an estimate of how many leaf blocks you *expect* the index to have.

If that is roughly close to the LEAF_BLOCK statistic you have, then you can assume that the index is probably not "fragmented" (although that is a term that can cover a multitude of things).

But unless you have a performance issue that you can *currently* tie back to this index, then I wouldn't worry too much about index fragmentation.

Answer (score 0):

A row lock is a row lock; as such it is very unlikely that this is due to index fragmentation (which is another topic).
A row lock is generally taken out by the application, and is normal behavior.